# How to include a word in front of each picker view value

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Essentially I have the following `UIPickerView` array that I am using to allow the user to easily POST values to `JSON`. The issue is I only need the numeric value to be sent not including the word "Page"

```
let stopPickerValues = ["Tap to Select Page #","Page 1", "Page 2", 
"Page 3", "Page 4", "Page 5", "Page 6", "Page 7", "Stop 8", "Stop 9", "Page 10"]
```

How can I show the word `Page` as a selection in the `UIPickerView` but only include the number once a value is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let selectedStr = stopPickerValues[row]
let str = selectedStr.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).first
print(str)
```